# Sort ArrayList<String[]> by any column and "print" result

Tags: android, sorting, arraylist

I filled array list with values. Each row is item with properties. Now I would like to sort items by one of properties and "print" them to textview.

```
ArrayList<String[]> arrayList = new ArrayList<String[]>();
final String[] rowToArray = new String[7];
rowToArray[0] = itemName;
rowToArray[1] = itemProperties1;
rowToArray[2] = itemProperties2;
rowToArray[3] = itemProperties3;
rowToArray[4] = itemProperties4;
rowToArray[5] = itemProperties5;
rowToArray[6] = itemProperties6;
arrayList.add(rowToArray);
```

Could you please help me to sort it by properties and then show me how to print item one by one with properties.

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT:**

**SOLVED BY [ppeterka66](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1667004/ppeterka-66)**

I just had to add his code and call **Collections.sort(arrayList,new StringArrayComparator(column));** where column is required column to be sortby.

```
int i=0;
final int column=2;
Collections.sort(arrayList,new StringArrayComparator(column));
for(String[] line :arrayList) 
    {
    Log.d(Integer.toString(i),line[column].toString());
    }
```

Comment: Consider creating your own class and change `ArrayList<String[]>` to `ArrayList<YourClass>`, then it will be easy to use `Collections.sort` and create your own `Comparator`.

Comment: I confirm solution made by ppeterka66. This code is working, easy to use and understand! Even for me, so I am sure nobody else will have problem : )

Answer (score 1):

```
Collections.sort
```

for example

```
class User {

    String name;
    String age;

    public User(String name, String age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(String age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
import java.util.Comparator;

public class ComparatorUser implements Comparator {

    public int compare(Object arg0, Object arg1) {
        User user0 = (User) arg0;
        User user1 = (User) arg1;

        int flag = user0.getAge().compareTo(user1.getAge());
        if (flag == 0) {
            return user0.getName().compareTo(user1.getName());
        } else {
            return flag;
        }
    }

}
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class SortTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List userlist = new ArrayList();
        userlist.add(new User("dd", "4"));
        userlist.add(new User("aa", "1"));
        userlist.add(new User("ee", "5"));
        userlist.add(new User("bb", "2"));
        userlist.add(new User("ff", "5"));
        userlist.add(new User("cc", "3"));
        userlist.add(new User("gg", "6"));

        ComparatorUser comparator = new ComparatorUser();
        Collections.sort(userlist, comparator);

        for (int i = 0; i < userlist.size(); i++) {
            User user_temp = (User) userlist.get(i);
            System.out.println(user_temp.getAge() + "," + user_temp.getName());
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: for example. better Learning

Comment: I think this answer is a good start to what the user is looking for (or could really use). FYI, I've upvoted both of your answers - now stop arguing and eat a waffle. :)

Answer (score 1):

You could create a reusable String[]  [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) you could specify which indexes to compare the arrays on:

```
public class StringArrayComparator implements Comparator<String[]> {
  //we store the index to compare the arrays by in this instance variable
  private final int stringIndexToCompare;

  //constructor accepting the value for the index to check
  public StringArrayComparator(int whichString) {
    stringIndexToCompare=whichString;
  }

  @Override
  public int compare(String[] o1, String[] o2) {
    //checking if any of the arrays is null
    if(o1==null)      { return o2==null?0:1; } //if o1 is null, o2 determines the resuult
    else if(o2==null) { return -1; } //this only gets evaluated if o1 is not null

    //get the strings, by checking if the arrays are long enough
    String first = o1.length>stringIndexToCompare?o1[stringIndexToCompare]:null;
    String second= o2.length>stringIndexToCompare?o2[stringIndexToCompare]:null;

    //null checking the strings themselves -- basically same as above
    if(first==null)          { return second==null?0:1; }
    else if(second==null)    { return -1; }

    //if both non-null, compare them.
    return first.compareTo(second);
  }
}
```

To be used on your list:

```
Collections.sort(myList,new StringArrayComparator(3));
```

Note: the 3 specifies the index of the array to be compared.

You didn't specify the expected output of how the printed string should look, but just to print the list, you could use this oneliner:

```
  System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(a.toArray()));
```

**EDIT**

> I would like to see something like Log.d("line number",column[0]+","+column[1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html)+","+column[2]+...);

Hey, that looks almost OK... Basically you only have to put it into a loop: this prints it line by line:

```
int lineNo=0;
for(String[] line :myList) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(++i); //line number, incrementing too

    //iterating through the elements of the array
    for(int col=0;col<line.lenght;col++) {
        sb.append(",");
        if(line[col]!=null) {  //check for null....
            sb.append(line[col]);
        }
    }
    Log.d(sb.toString()); //append the value from the builder to the log.
}
```

To get it in one big string:

```
int lineNo=0;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); //create it here
for(String[] line :myList) {
    sb.append(++i); //line number, incrementing too

    //iterating through the elements of the array
    for(int col=0;col<line.lenght;col++) {
        sb.append(",");
        if(line[col]!=null) {  //check for null....
            sb.append(line[col]);
        }
    }
    sb.append("\n"); //append line break
}
Log.d(sb.toString()); //append the value from the builder to the log.
```

Or, maybe it would be nicer (though slower) to use String.format() for this purpose,a s that offers better formatting:

```
 //assembly format string
 //if no line number was needed: String format = "";

 String format = "%d"; //line number, %d means integer
 for(int i=0;i<7;i++) {
    format+=",%20s"; //%20s means left aligned, 20 wide string
 }
 format += "\n"; //line break;

 int lineNumber=0;
 for(String[] line:myArray) {
     //if you didn't need the line number, it would be so easy here
     //String.format(format,line); //one line, but this doesn't have the line number yet...

     //with line numbers:
     int iamLazyNow = 0;
     String formatted = String.format(format,++lineNumber, 
          line[iamLazyNow++], line[iamLazyNow++],
          line[iamLazyNow++], line[iamLazyNow++],
          line[iamLazyNow++], line[iamLazyNow++],
          line[iamLazyNow++]); //practically one line, but ugly

     //you can append formatted to a StringBuilder, or print it here...
 }
```

Comment: Ok, this seems to be solution, could you just help me with output? I would like to see something like Log.d("line number",column[0]+","+column[1]+","+column[2]+...);

Comment: I have to thank you very very very much! Your code is great, simple and it is very easy to work with it. Also output is finally clear to me to, meaning you solved all my problems!!! I felt like breaking my head, but now I am happy! : )